# resize JFrame with maximize button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, window-resize

im sure if there is a way,  but if I have already have Jframes that work with the small screen.  Is there a way to make the elements of the screen resize to fit a screen if it is maximized?

What I mean is,  if the screen is 40x40,  and the pictures etc are located on that screen size the way I like,  but when I maximize the screen,  then the 40x40 part of the screen will be the same size,  and the screen will maximize to show the surrounding enlargement of screen without elements (basically looks like a surrounding huge gray area surrounding the original smaller screen).  I want to be able to enlarge the screen while keeping the elements in the same distance proportions.

I hope anyone can get what am trying to write.

Comment: You know I already tried to look up the answer before posting this.  And now you just give me tutorials to study instead of trying to really break it down and tell me how to do it.  I dont want to stay online researching for another many hours that is the reason I ask for help.  Yet it seems like you guys want to just boost your stackflow score by giving bullshi- responses that dont really help.  I mean thanks for the tutorial but i could have done that myself...and you are just trying to improve your reputations by giving links to DIY w/o having to actually take the time to tell how to do it

Comment: i mean I see that alot on stackflow,  alot of you give smart ass responses and treat the people asking the question like they are stupid because they dont know what you know.  And alot of you give links to tutorials.  And thats great to learn,  but if I have already for how many hours been researching...shit I just want the answer.  Its like i have been walking on a dirt road and I have a map which I dont understand because I dont know how to read maps - I ask you for directions, and you just give me another map and dont teach me how to understand that map as well...trying to boost ur SF score

Answer (score 1):

You're probably setting the sizes of elements yourself using `setPreferredSize()`, `setBounds()` etc. while using `setLayout(null)`. Use a Layout instead which will handle the resizing of components automatically.

Read [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add a container inside of the frame that you are expanding, and add constant variables as the dimensions of the container. Put the images in the container instead of the frame.

Comment: Abdul Fatir - What are you writing about?  Are you trying to make fun of the question I posted by writing im stupid or something?  Bijan

Comment: Not at all, constants are variables that can't be changed. (final)